# Optimizing DataReader Results: what is the concequence of leaving the values as objects?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, datareader

```
var list = new List<object[]>();
var fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
while(reader.Read()) {
    var array = new object[fieldCount];
    reader.GetValues(array);
    list.Add(array);
}
```

Given the simple code snippet above.  And assuming the values being retrieved are a mix of value types.

- Is there any speed advantage if you knew the types of each column before
  hand, and could properly call there typed methods to get (all) their
  values?
- Or is getting the typed values slowing the overall read process down?
- What trade-offs if any are there when leaving the data in object arrays, vs storing them in a typed entity?

Comment: Let's assume that you have a table in your database, which holds customers data and you want to retrieve some records from this table and make some processing on these data. In order to access the attributes of a customer object, you have to have a list of customer objects. A list of objects wouldn't fit.

Comment: In most database access, the greatest cost will be latency and transferring data over the wire. As such, your primary concern, on the C# side, should be ease of understanding the code. Using `object` everywhere makes the code harder to reason about. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper may be worth considering.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes.  It's micro-optimizing.  I'm being a bit over-kill here.  But it's a strong curiosity.

Comment: @mjwills yes. Speed of extraction is priority 1 IMO.  Keeping connection open time to a minimum.  So in larger/more-repeated queries, I'm micro-optimizing for this metric.  Once the data is extracted, there's less concern about coercing the data into what's needed.  But if there was some possible benefit, memory, or CPU that comes from using the .GetString(), .GetInt32() methods instead, I'd like to know.  Or are these methods simply casting under the hood.

Comment: `Keeping connection open time to a minimum` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @mjwills Things have likely changed a lot over the years, but there used to be two things that could kill application performance:
1) Connection open time.
2) The act of opening and closing a connection.

Comment: No.2 Has mostly been solved by connection pools and many frameworks even batch their queries together to minimize this.  Or even track the connection state to see if outstanding queries are are still active before finally closing.

Comment: No.1 Is one of those things that is not likely to be a problem today unless there is a significant number of queries being made concurrently.  And of course depends the the database being used.

Synchronous queries (very common) can end up reserving a connection for that instance.   The longer you are taking to finish a query, the longer other queued queries have to wait.  Pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any speed advantage if you knew the types of each column before hand, and could properly call there typed methods to get (all) their values?

Yes. Because your alternative is checking for the appropriate type e.g.:

```
if (obj is string)
{
 //Do string things
}
else if (obj is int)
{
 //Do int things
}
```

When knowing the type, simply cast:

```
string t = (string) obj;
```

> Or is getting the typed values slowing the overall read process down?

No. In fact you can´t get any faster than casting to the correct type.

> What trade-offs if any are there when leaving the data in object arrays, vs storing them in a typed entity?

Storing them in an object array is going to use more memory, since value-types are boxed as object.

Comment: This is partially what I expected to hear but wasn't sure.  Storing as an object array requires more memory because of boxing.

But isn't there unboxing overhead when using the .GetInt32(), .GetString(), .GetBoolean(), etc. methods?

If only temporarily, I'm curious if deferring that overhead until after the connection is closed would have any effect.

... Important note: for this example, at the end of the pipeline, the values would only be casted once.

Comment: After reviewing the source code for `SqlDataReader`, I'd like to confirm that this is the best answer.  GetValue and GetValues end up adding boxing overhead, but (because the way it's designed) the more specific typed values are retrieved from a specific SqlBuffer class that stores the values unboxed.

Comment: Just to be clear: We´re talking about very small amounts. A few more bytes for storing the boxed values vs (maybe) a nanosecond for casting. I would always go with the typed entity, it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: yes.  It's clearly appropriate to use the typed methods when possible.  For my data access library, I'm mapping fields to entities and am buffering the data into object arrays (per record) then apply the transformation after.  This is one of those potential optimizations that is not worth implementing.